# SQLite boolean values in Lua

Tags: sqlite, lua, coronasdk

I'm having some trouble finding an elegant solution to this. I'm creating an app using Corona that has a SQLite db. One of the columns in the db is a boolean. I know that SQLite uses `1` or `0` for `true` or `false`. I also know that Lua evaluates everything to true that isn't `false` or `nil`.

Is there some way to directly evaluate a SQLite boolean as true or false in Lua without having to do:

```
if(myVariable == 1)
```

I feel like this defeats the purpose of having a boolean column in the table since I could compare myVariable to anything. I'd like to just be able to write:

```
if(myVariable)
```

Is there a way to do this? Right now I think my only option is to store 1 for true and just leave false as `null` in the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. So, when Lua reads the column from the database, it cannot determine that the value is intended to be a Boolean rather than a number.

BTW, when `lsqlite3` stores a Lua Boolean using one of the `bind` methods, it *does* note that Lua intends to store a Boolean, and converts the value to integers 0 (`false`) and 1 (`true`).

Since you are programming in Lua, you'll have to accept the fact that Lua treats numbers as numbers, not as Booleans. My recommendation is that you convert the numbers to Booleans in Lua right after you read them from the database.